# What is the "if __name__ == '__main__'" block called?

Tags: python

I saw someone on a Python post refer to it in some way, but I cannot for the life of me find it again.
It was a pretty short, colloquial term, something like "gutter" or "blunk".

Is it a Python thing or do other languages call it something too?

Comment: I've seen somewhere was called `guard statement`, though `"conditional script" stanza` sounds more fancy. I'm looking forward to see if you find your answer to this.

Comment: How about 'Name-Main Idiom'?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/6045800) suggests "name/`__name__` guard". I would add to the pool "main guard"

Comment: Yes! I think it was 'main guard' or 'guard statement'! Thanks! I'm new to (posting on) SO, I can't mark one of your comments as answer, can I? Is it etiquette to have a marked answer?

Comment: linkcharger, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (and you can't "accept" a comment, comments are not meant to give answers)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, maybe you can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation up to [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/__main__.html) it's referred to as a "conditional script" stanza:

> It is this environment in which the idiomatic “conditional script” stanza causes a script to run:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     main()
> ```

This term is gone [since 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/__main__.html):

> a common idiom for conditionally executing code in a module when it is run as a script or with `python -m` but not when it is imported:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     # execute only if run as a script
>     main()
> ```

Comment: Nice catch! Though the term I saw was much more colloquial.. like it would appear in Urban Dictionary for code, like people actually use it in daily speech